# Loading overlay never disappears in config of Jenkins plugin

Tags: groovy, configuration, jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to add repeatable properties to the Jenkins plugin I'm developing, and created a test plugin to make make sure I was using them correctly.  My plugin seems to work fine, I can add as many properties as I want when I originally edit the config, and it saves and builds.  However, when I try to edit the config a second time, the config screen shows the loading overlay endlessly.  If I scroll down, I can see the properties I saved earlier are still there, but I can't edit anything.

My class looks like this:

```
public class RepeatableTest extends Builder {

    private List<Prop> property = new ArrayList<Prop>();


    @DataBoundConstructor
    public RepeatableTest(List<Prop> property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public List<Prop> getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) throws IOException {
        listener.getLogger().println(property.get(0).name);
        listener.getLogger().println(property.size());
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public DescriptorImpl getDescriptor() {
        return (DescriptorImpl)super.getDescriptor();
    }

    public static class Prop extends AbstractDescribableImpl<Prop> {
        public String name;

        public String getName(){
            return name;
        }

        @DataBoundConstructor
        public Prop(String name) {
            this.name = name;
        }

        @Extension
        public static class DescriptorImpl extends Descriptor<Prop> {
            @Override
            public String getDisplayName() {
                return "";
            }
        }
    }

    @Extension // This indicates to Jenkins that this is an implementation of an extension point.
    public static final class DescriptorImpl extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder> {

        private String phpLoc;

        public DescriptorImpl() {
            load();
        }

        public boolean isApplicable(Class<? extends AbstractProject> aClass) {
            // Indicates that this builder can be used with all kinds of project types 
            return true;
        }

        public String getDisplayName() {
            return "Repeatable Test";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean configure(StaplerRequest req, JSONObject formData) throws FormException {
            phpLoc = formData.getString("phpLoc");
            save();
            return super.configure(req,formData);
        }

        public String getPhpLoc() {
            return phpLoc;
        }
    }
}
```

My config.groovy looks like this:

```
package uitestplugin.uitest.RepeatableTest;

import lib.JenkinsTagLib
import lib.FormTagLib

def f = namespace(lib.FormTagLib)
t=namespace(JenkinsTagLib.class)

f.form{
    f.entry(title:"Properties"){
        f.repeatableProperty(field:"property")
    }
}
```

and my prop/config.groovy looks like this:

```
package uitestplugin.uitest.RepeatableTest.Prop;

def f = namespace(lib.FormTagLib)

f.entry(title:"Name", field:"name") {
    f.textbox()
}
```

The config.xml:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<project>
  <actions/>
  <description></description>
  <keepDependencies>false</keepDependencies>
  <properties/>
  <scm class="hudson.scm.NullSCM"/>
  <canRoam>true</canRoam>
  <disabled>false</disabled>
  <blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenDownstreamBuilding>
  <blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>false</blockBuildWhenUpstreamBuilding>
  <triggers/>
  <concurrentBuild>false</concurrentBuild>
  <builders>
    <uitestplugin.uitest.RepeatableTest plugin="ui-test@1.0-SNAPSHOT">
      <property>
        <uitestplugin.uitest.RepeatableTest_-Prop>
          <name>Prop1</name>
        </uitestplugin.uitest.RepeatableTest_-Prop>
        <uitestplugin.uitest.RepeatableTest_-Prop>
          <name>Prop2</name>
        </uitestplugin.uitest.RepeatableTest_-Prop>
      </property>
    </uitestplugin.uitest.RepeatableTest>
  </builders>
  <publishers/>
  <buildWrappers/>
</project>
```

Any ideas as to what could cause this?  I based a lot of the code from the ui-samples plugin (https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/UI+Samples+Plugin).

EDIT:  The current status of this is, well, I still haven't figured it out.  I've done more research and tried tons of different examples, but the farthest I ever get is what I described above.  It almost seems like you can't use repeatable through groovy.  Anyways, I have one more piece of information to add.  Using the web developer toolbar for Firefox, I can see that there is a Javascript error on the page.  The error is:

```
Timestamp: 10/3/2014 12:58:49 PM
Error: TypeError: prototypes is undefined
Source File: http://localhost:8080/adjuncts/e58fb488/lib/form/hetero-list/hetero-list.js
Line: 16
```

And the code this relates to is(I've marked line 16 with a comment at the end of the line):

```
// @include lib.form.dragdrop.dragdrop

// do the ones that extract innerHTML so that they can get their original HTML before
// other behavior rules change them (like YUI buttons.)
Behaviour.specify("DIV.hetero-list-container", 'hetero-list', -100, function(e) {
        e=$(e);
        if(isInsideRemovable(e))    return;

        // components for the add button
        var menu = document.createElement("SELECT");
        var btns = findElementsBySelector(e,"INPUT.hetero-list-add"),
            btn = btns[btns.length-1]; // In case nested content also uses hetero-list
        YAHOO.util.Dom.insertAfter(menu,btn);

        var prototypes = $(e.lastChild);
        while(!prototypes.hasClassName("prototypes")) //LINE 16, ERROR IS HERE
            prototypes = prototypes.previous();
        var insertionPoint = prototypes.previous();    // this is where the new item is inserted.

        // extract templates
        var templates = []; var i=0;
        $(prototypes).childElements().each(function (n) {
            var name = n.getAttribute("name");
            var tooltip = n.getAttribute("tooltip");
            var descriptorId = n.getAttribute("descriptorId");
            menu.options[i] = new Option(n.getAttribute("title"),""+i);
            templates.push({html:n.innerHTML, name:name, tooltip:tooltip,descriptorId:descriptorId});
            i++;
        });
        Element.remove(prototypes);

        var withDragDrop = initContainerDD(e);

        var menuAlign = (btn.getAttribute("menualign")||"tl-bl");

        var menuButton = new YAHOO.widget.Button(btn, { type: "menu", menu: menu, menualignment: menuAlign.split("-") });
        $(menuButton._button).addClassName(btn.className);    // copy class names
        $(menuButton._button).setAttribute("suffix",btn.getAttribute("suffix"));
        menuButton.getMenu().clickEvent.subscribe(function(type,args,value) {
            var item = args[1];
            if (item.cfg.getProperty("disabled"))   return;
            var t = templates[parseInt(item.value)];

            var nc = document.createElement("div");
            nc.className = "repeated-chunk";
            nc.setAttribute("name",t.name);
            nc.setAttribute("descriptorId",t.descriptorId);
            nc.innerHTML = t.html;
            $(nc).setOpacity(0);

            var scroll = document.body.scrollTop;

            renderOnDemand(findElementsBySelector(nc,"TR.config-page")[0],function() {
                function findInsertionPoint() {
                    // given the element to be inserted 'prospect',
                    // and the array of existing items 'current',
                    // and preferred ordering function, return the position in the array
                    // the prospect should be inserted.
                    // (for example 0 if it should be the first item)
                    function findBestPosition(prospect,current,order) {
                        function desirability(pos) {
                            var count=0;
                            for (var i=0; i<current.length; i++) {
                                if ((i<pos) == (order(current[i])<=order(prospect)))
                                    count++;
                            }
                            return count;
                        }

                        var bestScore = -1;
                        var bestPos = 0;
                        for (var i=0; i<=current.length; i++) {
                            var d = desirability(i);
                            if (bestScore<=d) {// prefer to insert them toward the end
                                bestScore = d;
                                bestPos = i;
                            }
                        }
                        return bestPos;
                    }

                    var current = e.childElements().findAll(function(e) {return e.match("DIV.repeated-chunk")});

                    function o(did) {
                        if (Object.isElement(did))
                            did = did.getAttribute("descriptorId");
                        for (var i=0; i<templates.length; i++)
                            if (templates[i].descriptorId==did)
                                return i;
                        return 0; // can't happen
                    }

                    var bestPos = findBestPosition(t.descriptorId, current, o);
                    if (bestPos<current.length)
                        return current[bestPos];
                    else
                        return insertionPoint;
                }
                (e.hasClassName("honor-order") ? findInsertionPoint() : insertionPoint).insert({before:nc});

                if(withDragDrop)    prepareDD(nc);

                new YAHOO.util.Anim(nc, {
                    opacity: { to:1 }
                }, 0.2, YAHOO.util.Easing.easeIn).animate();

                Behaviour.applySubtree(nc,true);
                ensureVisible(nc);
                layoutUpdateCallback.call();
            },true);
        });

        menuButton.getMenu().renderEvent.subscribe(function() {
            // hook up tooltip for menu items
            var items = menuButton.getMenu().getItems();
            for(i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                var t = templates[i].tooltip;
                if(t!=null)
                    applyTooltip(items[i].element,t);
            }
        });

        if (e.hasClassName("one-each")) {
            // does this container already has a ocnfigured instance of the specified descriptor ID?
            function has(id) {
                return Prototype.Selector.find(e.childElements(),"DIV.repeated-chunk[descriptorId=\""+id+"\"]")!=null;
            }

            menuButton.getMenu().showEvent.subscribe(function() {
                var items = menuButton.getMenu().getItems();
                for(i=0; i<items.length; i++) {
                    items[i].cfg.setProperty("disabled",has(templates[i].descriptorId));
                }
            });
        }
    });

Behaviour.specify("DIV.dd-handle", 'hetero-list', -100, function(e) {
        e=$(e);
        e.on("mouseover",function() {
            $(this).up(".repeated-chunk").addClassName("hover");
        });
        e.on("mouseout",function() {
            $(this).up(".repeated-chunk").removeClassName("hover");
        });
});
```

I hope this is enough information to solve the problem.  Any suggestions (even if they aren't complete answers) are really appreciated.

Comment: what does the config.xml look like this is found at jenkins-server/job/config.xml

Comment: Isn't it a bug in a jenkins version You use? Google for it.

Comment: @KeepCalmAndCarryOn I'll update the question with the config.xml.

Comment: @Opal I've tried Googling, but didn't find anything.  Is there a better way to word my question so I could try again?  Also, I updated my Jenkins version but the problem persisted.

Comment: We had this problem some time ago, don't remember the details. It's finished with changing jenkins version.

Comment: @Opal did you run in to this issue when you were developing a custom plugin?

Comment: No, but I suppose that i may have nothing to do with plugin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While not an exact answer, I did find a way to get this working.  For some reason, putting the repeatableProperty in an advanced block stopped the javascript error from happening, so everything loaded fine.

So, my config.groovy for RepeatableTest looked like this:

```
package uitestplugin.uitest.RepeatableTest;

f = namespace(lib.FormTagLib)

f.advanced{
    f.entry(title:"Properties"){
        f.repeatableProperty(field:"property", minimum:"1"){
        }
    }
}
```

My config.groovy for Prop1 looked like this:

```
package uitestplugin.uitest.Prop1;

def f = namespace(lib.FormTagLib)

f.entry(title:"Name",field:"name") {
    f.textbox()
}

f.entry {
    div(align:"left") {
        input(type:"button",value:"Delete",class:"repeatable-delete")
    }
}
```

My prop 1 looked like this:

```
public class Prop1 extends AbstractDescribableImpl<Prop1> {
    private final String name;

    public String getName(){
        return name;
    }

    @DataBoundConstructor
    public Prop1( String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Extension
    public static class DescriptorImpl extends Descriptor<Prop1> {
        @Override
        public String getDisplayName() {
            return "";
        }
    }
}
```

And my RepeatableTest.java looked like this:

```
public class RepeatableTest extends Builder {

    private final List<Prop1> property;


    // Fields in config.jelly must match the parameter names in the "DataBoundConstructor"
    @DataBoundConstructor
    public RepeatableTest(List<Prop1> property) {
        this.property = property;
    }

    public List<Prop1> getProperty() {
        return property;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean perform(AbstractBuild build, Launcher launcher, BuildListener listener) throws IOException {
        //Doesn't matter
    }

    @Override
    public DescriptorImpl getDescriptor() {
        return (DescriptorImpl)super.getDescriptor();
    }

    @Extension // This indicates to Jenkins that this is an implementation of an extension point.
    public static final class DescriptorImpl extends BuildStepDescriptor<Builder> {

        private String phpLoc;

        public DescriptorImpl() {
            load();
        }

        public boolean isApplicable(Class<? extends AbstractProject> aClass) {
            // Indicates that this builder can be used with all kinds of project types 
            return true;
        }

        public String getDisplayName() {
            return "Repeatable Test";
        }

        @Override
        public boolean configure(StaplerRequest req, JSONObject formData) throws FormException {
            phpLoc = formData.getString("phpLoc");
            save();
            return super.configure(req,formData);
        }

        public String getPhpLoc() {
            return phpLoc;
        }
    }
}
```